# JBoss AS 7 Datasource Configuration - Transaction not active

Tags: java, cdi, jboss7.x

I have this datasource configuration on my `JBOSS AS 7` in standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MyJndiDS" pool-name="MyPoolDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="false" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:postgresql://192.168.2.125:5432/t_report
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        org.postgresql
                    </driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>
                        TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                    </transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>
                            3
                        </min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>
                            7
                        </max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>
                            true
                        </prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>
                            false
                        </use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>
                            FailingConnectionOnly
                        </flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            my_user
                        </user-name>
                        <password>
                            my_pass
                        </password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                            32
                        </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
...
...
            </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

And when I login and logout 7 times with one and the same user the next time i try to login I get `Transaction not active` error. How can I fix this? I don't want to increase the `max-pool-size`.  Here is my logout method:

```
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
@Inject ExternalContext ec;

public void validateUserLogOut() {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ec.getRequest();
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    this.setUserLoggedIn(false);
    navigation.logout();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is less the datasource (this only exposes it), but rather the fact that the login module seems to keep connections open and is not returning them into the pool.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to return the connections to the pool after logout?

Comment: @Maistora if you found the solution to your questions, maybe you you can post it also: for the sake of the completeness of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to request of `user503413` I will admit the mistake I've made with a disgrace: I have forgotten to close the connection after using it (`connection.close()`). If you don't close your connection it will not return it to the pool and since you've limited and reached the `max-pool-size` (7 in my case) no new connection is going to be created. So the lesson here is always be sure to close your `connections`. Also close your `prepared statements` or else you'll get a *memory leak*.